# Can't Edit Item - <% if @user.errors.any? %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Im using Simple Form gem.

When I try to update item with INVALID Data for instancing missing out some information like the Price. Rails is suppose to redirect to the edit view. As you can see by the controller.

**Blow is the Update Method for the Items Controller**

```
  def update
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    if @item.update(item_params)
       redirect_to @item
       flash[:success] = 'Item was successfully updated.'
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Item didn't update"
      render "edit"
    end
  end
```

However it doesn't. I just get this error.

Showing

```
/Users/josep/Documents/Safsy/Website/Safsy/Safsy/app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
```

Below is _error.messages.html.erb

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Partial is rendered inside my applications.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all',
                                           'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500,900,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/r29/html5.min.js">
      </script>
    <![endif]-->
  <title>Safsy - The Safest Way To Shop</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <%= yield :sliderhome %>
    <div class="container">
      <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Views/Items/edit.html.erb

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1><%=@item.title  %> <small> Edit</small></h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class=“row”>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
          <%= simple_form_for @item do |f| %>
            <%= f.input :image%>
            <%= f.input :title%>
            <%= f.input :price %>
            <%= f.input :description %>
            <%= f.button :submit, "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Thanks for any help in advance**

Comment: you have `@item` .. inside the `update` not the `@user` ..

Comment: @ArupRakshit its the items controller. Its suppose to be items because im updating the item not the user... Or am i missing something?

Comment: Where is @user set? It needs to be set somewhere

Comment: @joeyk16 Actually you are missing the whole point. This line should be `<% if @user.errors.any? %>`  `<% if @item.errors.any? %>` as you have `@item` in your update not `@user`. And this line `<% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>` too need to be changed

Comment: How are you rendering that partial? Post that code.

Comment: @Pavan Yes i did know that from the start. Problem is if i change it to `<% if @item.errors.any? %>` it will wreck many things because that partial is in my application.html.erb. So it shows on every web page. 

I did just define @user in the controller  `@user = User.find(params[:id])` and it works but im hoping there's a better way. I shouldnt have `@user` in my Items Edit method.

Comment: Please post your edit.html.erb of items

Comment: @Pavan I just did. Thanks

Comment: @Pavan Soz i also post Items edit.html.erb too. Thank you

Comment: You are not rendering that partial in `application.html.erb`. Just change `@user` to `@item` in your `_error_messages.html.erb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming because your `error` partial has `@user` object, but your form has `@item` object, below is the solution

Make your `error` partial work for every object, in your item form change the `render 'shared/error_messages'` line to this

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', form_object: @item %>
```

and change your `_error_messages.html.erb` to

```
<% if form_object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(form_object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% form_object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

So as you are using this partial in `application` layout, pass the form object in the partial as I have done above! It will resolve your problem!

In this way, your error will be fixed and your code will dry up. Hope that helps!

Comment: this is a very good way. Thank you. Many of my User Integration Tests will now break but this is great. Thank you.